# How can i do 2^0.3 (exponent below 1) using integers?

Tags: solidity, math

simple problem, but i can't seem to wrap my head around it in solidity.

how can i do 2^0.3 (exponent smaller then 1) in solidity using integers.

thanks in advance
K.

Comment: Solidity can only do exponentiation of integers where the base of the exponent can be a signed or unsigned integer and the exponent is an unsigned integer. The EVM does not have direct support for fractions or fixed point numbers, so this isn't an issue with solidity.

Comment: However, one way around the problem would be to use integers to model a floating point number, and use a Taylor series for `a^b` to compute the exponent. [This](https://github.com/gnosis/util-contracts/blob/master/contracts/Math.sol) seems to have an implementation of `e^x.